# how to convert a raw readme file to html formated document after geting it from github in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, github-api, readme

I used the following controller but how to format each line of the README.MD raw file to html document

```
    angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope, Slim,$sce) {
    Slim.getReadme().then(function(resp) {
      $scope.readme = $sce.trustAsHtml(resp.data);
    }).catch(function(resp) {
      console.log("catch", resp);
    });
  })
  .service('Slim', function($http) {
    return {
      getReadme: function() {
        return $http.get("https://api.github.com/repos/btford/angular-markdown-directive/readme", {
          headers: {
            "Accept": "application/vnd.github.v3.raw"
          }
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

I would be excited to know transformation of raw readme file to a formatted html page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..how to format each line of the README.MD raw file to html document..

Response you are getting from github API is plain markdown. So you just need to:

- render the `response.data` using a suitable markdown-to-html library before you actually bind it to scope. Here's an example using [marked.js](https://github.com/chjj/marked)

  ```
   $scope.readme = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.parseMD(resp.data));
  ```

  Where parseMD is a function that returns rendered HTML

  ```
   $scope.parseMD = function(md_content){
        return marked(md_content);
   }
  ```
- bind the output as html using `ng-bind-html`

  ```
   <div ng-bind-html="readme"></div>
  ```

What you do in `parseMD` is really upto you, its just a matter of choice. Here are some popular markdown-to-HTML libraries:

- [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked)  // Easy to understand/dive into the code
- [markdown-js](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js) // supports `maruku` as-well-as `gruber` dialect
- [showdown.js](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) // forked as `PageDown` in stackexchange

All these libraries seem to go well with [Github Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/enterprise/11.10.340/user/articles/github-flavored-markdown/)

Here's the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/KYlvCS51BigJzcn8NkQ2?p=preview)

Comment: how can i just add css to each in the parsed html, its would be more helpful if you add this !

Answer (score 1):

There are plugins that compile markdown to html.
One of those is markdown.js by evilstreak:

https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into [showdownjs](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown), take raw text and convert it to html like so.

```
var converter = new showdown.Converter(),
    text      = '#hello, markdown!',
    html      = converter.makeHtml(text);
```